# Al borrar un QGraphicsItem de un QGraphicsScene se cierra el programa

Tags: c++, qt

Estoy intentando modificar el código de un tutorial sobre `QGraphicsView` encontrado [aquí](https://www.bogotobogo.com/Qt/Qt5_QGraphicsView_animation.php)

Básicamente lo que hace es crear unos objetos derivados de `QGraphicsItem`, los cuales quedan confinados en un cuadrado cuyas dimensiones son las mismas que los límites de la escena. Estos objetos cuando encuentran los límites de la escena rebotan, y cuando chocan entre ellos cambian de color.

Pues bien, mi modificación pretende que en lugar de cambiar de color, desaparezcan, es decir, los quiero sacar de la escena. Para ello modifico la función original:

```
void MyItem::paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem *option, QWidget *widget)
{
    QRectF rect = boundingRect();

    // basic collision detection

    if(scene()->collidingItems(this).isEmpty())
    {
        // no collision
        QPen pen(Qt::green, 5);
        painter->setPen(pen);
    }
    else
    {
        // collision !!!
        QPen pen(Qt::red, 5);
        painter->setPen(pen);

        // set the position
        doCollision();
    }

    painter->drawEllipse(rect);
}
```

Por ésta:

```
void MyItem::paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem *option, QWidget *widget)
{
    QRectF rect = boundingRect();

    // basic collision detection

    if(scene()->collidingItems(this).isEmpty())
    {
        // no collision
        QPen pen(Qt::green, 5);
        painter->setPen(pen);
    }
    else
    {
        // collision !!!
        EliminarItem(); //<----Esta es la unica modificacion
        QPen pen(Qt::red, 5);
        painter->setPen(pen);
        // set the position
        doCollision();
    }

    painter->drawEllipse(rect);
}
```

(Básicamente la modificación consiste en hacer una llamada a la función `EliminarItem()` en caso de colisión)

Y esta función `EliminarItem()` hace lo siguiente:

```
void MyItem::EliminarItem()
{
    for (QGraphicsItem* i : scene()->collidingItems(this))
    {
        MyItem* itemBorrar = dynamic_cast<MyItem*>(i);
        if (itemBorrar)
        {
            //scene()->removeItem(itemBorrar);
            //scene()->update(itemBorrar->boundingRect());
            //delete itemBorrar;
            qDebug()<<itemBorrar;
        }
    }
}
```

Bueno, las líneas están comentadas porque me provocan el error. El item para borrar existe, como se muestra en `qDebug()`, pero el programa falla y se cierra.

No pongo todo el código porque está copiado del tutorial, pero si es necesario lo añado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema es que estás tratando que un nodo se borre a si mismo...

```
void MyItem::EliminarItem() // <<--- Estas en MyItem
{
    for (QGraphicsItem* i : scene()->collidingItems(this)) // Buscar items que colisionan
    {
        MyItem* itemBorrar = dynamic_cast<MyItem*>(i); // Elemento de MyItem
        if (itemBorrar)
        {
            delete itemBorrar; // <<--- Te estas borrando a ti mismo
        }
    }
}
```

El encargado de hacer esta tarea no puede ser el propio item porque no puede borrarse a si mismo ya que al hacerlo creas inconsistencias en memoria:

- La función `EliminarItem` sigue ejecutándose... pero su `this` apunta a un objeto borrado (cualquier uso del mismo, implícito o explícito será dañino)
- La función `paint` también continuará su ejecución con el mismo resultado (cualquier acceso a `this` será destructivo)

Necesitas un elemento externo donde apuntar que se debe borrar ese objeto. En este caso puede ser el `Dialog` (solución rápida), aunque lo más recomendable es que creases una clase que hiciese las veces de gestor de la escena:

**Dialog.h**

```
class Dialog
{
public:

    void DeleteItem(MyItem* item)
    { itemsToDelete.push_back(item); }

private:

  std::vector<MyItem*> itemsToDelete;

private slots:

  void RefreshScene();
};
```

**Dialog.cpp**

```
Dialog::Dialog(QWidget *parent) :
    QDialog(parent),
    ui(new Ui::Dialog)
{
    // ...

    for(int i = 0; i < itemCount; i++)
    {
      MyItem *item = new MyItem(this);
      scene->addItem(item);
    }

    timer = new QTimer(this);
    connect(timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), SLOT(RefreshScene()));
    timer->start(100);
}

void Dialog::RefreshScene();
{
  for(MyItem * item : itemsToDelete)
  {
    scene->removeItem(item);  
    delete item;
  }
  itemsToDelete.clear();

  scene.advance();
}
```

**MyItem.h**

```
class MyItem : public QGraphicsItem
{
public:
    MyItem(Dialog * dialog);

    // ...
};
```

**MyItem.cpp**

```
MyItem::MyItem(Dialog * dialog)
  : sceneManager{dialog}
{
  // ...
}

void MyItem::paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem *option, QWidget *widget)
{
    QRectF rect = boundingRect();

    // basic collision detection

    if(scene()->collidingItems(this).isEmpty())
    {
        // no collision
        QPen pen(Qt::green, 5);
        painter->setPen(pen);
        painter->drawEllipse(rect);
    }
    else
    {
        // collision !!!
        sceneManager->DeleteItem(this);
    }
}
```

Comment: @Trauma Podría ser una solución, pero yo no la pongo como respuesta si no puedo probarlo antes